# what is the " keep in touch" mean at the end of interview?

Tags: interviewing

When I have finished phone screening, the interviewer had have said "keep in touch".

so is this green light? or just polite thing?

Comment: @mcknz I'm not sure the interviewee in this case has been "rejected". It's just a phone screening at this point. "Keep in touch" just expresses the desire to keep the communications channels open.

Comment: @Brandin yeah, it's not the same question, but it's essentially the same answer (it's a polite thing) no matter the context.

Comment: @mcknz oh for crying out loud!  I could see you going through a math textbook eliminating all but one question where the answer is "6".  makes about as much sense.

Comment: @RichardU hah, yes I see what you mean, we could point 758 questions to the answer that is "No." I would argue in this case that the questions are similar enough, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

It's simply a polite phrase meant to imply that they will get back in touch with you if they have more news at a later time.

What you should be doing after the interview is emailing this interviewer and thanking them for their time, and for bringing this opportunity to your attention.

Comment: Does thanking mail help to me or just polite?

Comment: @Nashile - it's polite, and it ***can*** help you, because the interviewer will have a better opinion of you. It's kind of a standard business practice. If you do it, you're simply following the rules. If you don't, it's not a mortal insult, but the interviewer is far more likely to think poorly of you.

Answer (score 1):

It may mean one of the two things.

- They are not sure if you are the right person for the job, but you are promising. They will interview other candidates and if you are the best in bunch or at least one of them, they will get back to you, but they think they can find a better candidate among other applications.
- The position is not officially open yet, but there is a strong probability that they will hire someone soon. When that time comes, they want to touch base with you and see if you are still available and interested in working for them.

In either case, if you are in need of a job to pay the bills tomorrow, I would keep looking for other opportunities. But if you already have a job and looking for a better opportunity, keep them in mind and occasionally contact the interviewer (if you have his/her contact info given to you officially, not sneaking around and finding it in not so kosher ways) to see if there are any developments. By the way, occasionally doesn't mean weekly or more frequent. It is more like every month or 6 weeks, just to stay alive in the memory, not fading away. More, may look desperate and annoying/pesky.

But as the other answer indicated, definitely write a thank you note for the time interviewer take out of his/her day to talk to you and show some level of enthusiasm that you feel working for their organization, pinpointing some of your strong traits, with respect to the position requirements. First off it is a polite thing to do but more importantly, if you do it, you will be perceived as professional and if the choice comes down to selection one of the two people, and the other one did not write a thank you note, guess who will come ahead in the process ? Need I say more ?